# sum rows in a nested list in R

Tags: r

I have a nested list coming out of a program its length is 100. I need to sum all elements of first row and all elements of 2nd row. Here a a small reproducible example. What I need is sum of 1+3+5+7= 16 and sum of 2+4+6+8= 20 as a vector or matrix.

```
 l1<-as.matrix(c(1,2))
 l2<-as.matrix(c(3,4))
 l3<-as.matrix(c(5,6))
 l4<-as.matrix(c(7,8))
 ll1<-list(l1,l2)
 ll2<-list(l3,l4)
 lll<-list(ll1,ll2)

   lll
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2

 [[1]][[2]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    3
 [2,]    4


 [[2]]
 [[2]][[1]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    6

 [[2]][[2]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    7
 [2,]    8
```

Comment: I havent used dput but I can check. There is a reproducible code with small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `base R` by removing the nested `list` to a single `list` using `do.call(c` then `cbind` the elements of the `list` and get the `rowSums`

```
rowSums(do.call(cbind, do.call(c, lll)))
#[1] 16 20
```

---

Or otherwise we can `unlist`, create a `matrix` with 2 columns, and get the `colSums`

```
colSums(matrix(unlist(lll), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
#[1] 16 20
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the `purrr` package helpful for the function `flatten()` because it only removes one level of the hierarchy of the lists:

```
library(magrittr) #for pipes
library(purrr) #for flatten
lll %>% flatten %>% as.data.frame %>% rowSums
```

Based on akrun's answer it is similar to `do.call(c, lll)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce`in base R:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(Reduce(c, lll), rowSums))
#[1] 16 20
```